# Java decompiler, open jar excecutable file in eclipse and see source code

Tags: java, eclipse, decompiler

I have downloaded Java decompiler jd-eclipse-2.0.0.zip and followed the steps to install it in eclipse.

[image]

I want to open a jar executable file in eclipse to see its source code but I don't know how to open it.

My question is:  how can I open it in eclipse to see its source code?

Comment: Are you sure it can decompile JARs and not only `.class` files? Because if we're talking about [this](https://github.com/java-decompiler/jd-eclipse) it looks like it can only open `.class` files.

Comment: Note that decompilers don't show you the original source code. What you get may still be quite hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unzip the .jar file. (A jar file is really a zip file), and then open the .class files in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use two different decompilers, depending on whether the class file is a dependency of something in Eclipse, or outside of Eclipse.

In Eclipse, you should go to the marketplace client and install "Enhanced Class Decompiler" (currently at version 3.1.1).

Outside of Eclipse, install the JD-gui desktop app at the same site where you got jd-eclipse.  In your OS, set a file association for ".class" to open in jd-gui.

Now, if you are using a class file in Eclipse, you can decompile it just by viewing it.  If you're looking at the contents of a jar file in a file explorer, outside of Eclipse, if you open the class file, it will open in jd-gui.